SSIS error 'Opening a rowset for "<view>" failed. Check that the object exists in the database' when running in new VM
I have an SSIS job that exports data from a SQL view to a flat file. The view is on Server1 and has a JOIN to a table on Server2. The ssis package is running in Visual Studio 2022. I can work with it and run it from my current VM no problem. It is deployed to SQL Server and runs from there without issue. I'm getting a new VM and am testing to make sure everything is set up correctly. In the new VM I get an error on any data flow task that is connected to a view with a join to Server2. If I comment out the join to Server2, the error goes away.

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC02020E8 Error at notes [OLE DB Source 1
[113]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
Error at notes [OLE DB Source 1 [113]]: Opening a rowset for "view"
failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

I spent a couple hours troubleshooting various things, during which time I was switching between opening it in my current VM and new VM. It always works in the current VM. It did seem to work one time in the new VM and I was able to create a file. I closed and reopened the job and it has not worked in the new VM since. Wondering if there is some VS config that could be different between the two installations that would cause this. Delay Validation is set to False in both instances. The new VM has Windows 11 installed and I believe current is 10, so thinking it could potentially be something to do with Windows 11.

Did more troubleshooting and evetually got a different error related to failed connection for NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON.
The issue had to do with Kerberos Delegation and Credential Guard. In our environment Linked Servers are configured for the SQL Server Service Account to be able to delegate Kerberos credentials to the SQL Servers. It was configured to allow Full Delegation. Credential Guard is a feature in Windows that for Windows 11 Enterprise is enabled by default. It does not allow for Full Delegation.
After flipping the SQL Server Service Account to use Constrained Delegation for the SPNs it started working with Credential Guard enabled. This was done with Powershell. An example command for a SQL Server is ‘Set-ADUser -Identity "<ServiceAccount>" -Add @{'msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo'='MSSQLSvc/Castor.healthshareoregon.org:1433'}’
